# Server to Server Communication with Java

Tags: java, networking

I am currently developing a game, and would like to separate the login server from the game server. While I am experienced with client-server networking, I have never done any work communicating between servers. What are some standard or accepted methods of accomplishing this? My current topology(?) is to have the game client connect to the game server, handle all logging in and authentication, and then start processing game data/packets. What I would like to do, is split the login server and game server into separate entities, such that the client will initially connect to the login server, after proper authentication has been reached, send the client over to the game server and start processing game data.

What would be an acceptable way of handling this?

EDIT: It seems the intention of the question may be unclear. My question is, is there some sort of functionality that would allow server-server communication, OTHER than creating the login server as a client to the game server?

Comment: Some sort of login token?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, There is not. One of the two parties always needs to be listening for connections while the other end connects to it.

Comment: Thanks, that's all I needed to know.